# Parsing incomplete OpenXML document

Tags: c#, excel, xml

Here is a sample of a document with ".xls" extension that I assume is part of some OpenXml zip archive (i have just the xls file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <Author>Some Author</Author>
        <LastAuthor>Something</LastAuthor>
        <Company>Some random company</Company>
    </DocumentProperties>

    <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    </ExcelWorkbook>
    
    <!--Styles removed-->
    
    <Worksheet ss:Name="WB1">

        <Table>

            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="100" ss:Span="100"/>
            <Row ss:StyleID="tableHeader">
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Random column 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Random column 2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Random column 3</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">random value 1</Data>
                </Cell> 
            </Row>
            <Row ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">random value 2</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="tableRow">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">random value 3</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <Selected/>
            <Zoom>90</Zoom>
            <FreezePanes/>
            <FrozenNoSplit/>
            <SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
            <TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
            <ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The question is, what would be a fast way to parse this document?
What I've tried so far:

- Open an OleDbConnection using the Microsoft provider: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 1';` which throws the following exception: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'External table is not in the expected format.'` when trying to open a connection. I've also switched between Excel 12 and 8 with same result.
- Open the file using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` but it throws an error saying: `System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.'` most likely because the file is not in a zipped archive specific to OpenXml structure.
  `using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))`

Even if I try to open the said file with Excel, it says that The format and extension don't match, and I agree. It's basically just an xml file renamed as xls, but still, it opens as an Excel spreadsheet.

Should I treat this as an actual XML or is there some parsing tool that can help me read this so called "xls" file?

Comment: Firstly, .xls files are not OpenXml so that's a bit confusing.  Where did the XML come from?  That aside, have you seen this? ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet

Comment: I suspect somebody used the excel export in XML to create the file.  I've tried this in the past and then tried import without success.  Use Oledb  on the original xlsx file.